# How to catch if user clicks back button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this snippet, it works in all actions except if user clicks back button to leave the page.

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () 
{
    $.post("track.php", 
    {
        ip: ip,
        referer: referer,
    });
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () 
{
    $.post("track.php", 
    {
        ip: ip,
        referer: referer,
    });
});

$(window).unload(function () 
{
    $.post("track.php", 
    {
        ip: ip,
        referer: referer,
    });
});
```

Is it possible to catch if user clicks back button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your ajax request synchronous. This doesn't work in opera last I checked though.

```
$.ajax({
    async: false
});
```